# How to create a unique scope each time a directive is called (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a page with 'widgets'. I've created directive/controller/factory/template files, and everything is working fine when using only 1 per page, but there's a problem when I use multiple.

My directive:

```
app.directive('widget', ['widgets', function(widgets){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
            
            // Send attributes to template
            scope.widget = {
                id      : attrs.id,
                type    : attrs.type,
                view    : attrs.view
            }
            
        },
        templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
            return false || 'tpl/widgets/' + attrs.type + 's.html';
        }
    }
}])
```

My templateUrl file:

```
<div ng-controller="Widgets">
    {{widget.id}}
</div>
```

---

If I add the following code to my main HTML file

```
<widget id="widget_1" type="table" view="basic"></widget>
```

The output is:

> widget_1

But when I add 2 widgets, for example:

```
<widget id="widget_1" type="table" view="basic" views="basic"></widget>
<widget id="widget_2" type="table" view="basic" views="basic"></widget>
```

The output is:

> widget_2
>
> widget_2

Since there's only one `scope.widget` which is overwritten each time a new 'widget' is created (I assume..).

---

**Is there a way to create a unique scope/var each time a new widget is created?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isolate scope`

```
app.directive('widget', ['widgets', function(widgets){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 

            // Send attributes to template
            scope.widget = {
                id      : attrs.id,
                type    : attrs.type,
                view    : attrs.view
            }

        },
        templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
            return false || 'tpl/widgets/' + attrs.type + 's.html';
        }
    }
}])
```

To better understand concept of `scope` in `directive`:

Please refer to this link : "http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/"

Comment: Oh wow. I've tried all kinds of 'hacking' with controllers and weird workarounds... Just adding `scope: {},` instantly solved the problem. Never thought it was this simple. Thanks for the extra info too!

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal: Welcome!! :-) Please do accept , if find useful!!

Comment: I will! But I had to wait a few minutes before I could :)

Comment: Actually, this brings a new problem.. My template file now doesn't have access to the $scope anymore. Is there a way to fix that too? All my $scope variables like `{{username}}` can't be displayed anymore in my template file.

Comment: If You  mean the $scope of the parent, try using "scope:true" !!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks again! I'm quite new to directives, I always skipped them because of all the scope 'problems'. Reading your link now too.. it's actually not that hard.. :)

Comment: Yeah !! I also hope that the link will help you understand scopes in a much better way !! Do read :-)